# Texture issue while using THREE.TextureLoader over deprecated THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was using this function to add Texture on a Cylinder.

```
function createElementMaterial() {
    THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
    var t = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( IMG_MACHINE );
    t.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    t.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    t.offset.x = 90/(2*Math.PI);
    var m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    m.map = t;
    return m;
}
```

which is working and adds Texture, but in console it sets a warning message.

> THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture has been deprecated. Use
>   THREE.TextureLoader() instead.

Then following [this](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader) documentation from [threejs.org](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader). I changed the function to this.

```
function createElementMaterial() {
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    // load a resource
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        IMG_MACHINE,
        // Function when resource is loaded
        function ( texture ) {
            // do something with the texture
                texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                texture.offset.x = 90/(2*Math.PI);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                map: texture
            } );
        },
        // Function called when download progresses
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        // Function called when download errors
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( 'An error happened' );
        }
    );
}
```

With this code I am not being able to get that texture wrapping cylinder. Here's the before and after image.
TIA.
[image: Before and After using THREE.TextureLoader()]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to return a material from your function. You can do it like this:

```
function createElementMaterial() {

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(); // create a material

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
        // resource URL
        IMG_MACHINE,
        // Function when resource is loaded
        function ( texture ) {
            // do something with the texture
                texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                texture.offset.x = 90/(2*Math.PI);
                material.map = texture; // set the material's map when when the texture is loaded
        },
        // Function called when download progresses
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        // Function called when download errors
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( 'An error happened' );
        }
    );
    return material; // return the material
}
```

Comment: Thanks @prisoner849.